# sas if then else statement

Tags: if-statement, sas

I have this code below, I need it to set elig_factor[2] to 1 when status is =1 and hudadmin is in 1 or 2 or 3 else set elgi_factor[2] =0. But it sets elig_factor[2] = 0 anyway.  Can  someone please help?

```
if ("&r_start" eq 1) then 
 do;
 if ( 2011<=built <= 2014) then elig_factor[1] = '1';
 else elig_factor[1] = '0';

 if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '1') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
    else elig_factor[2] = '0';
  if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '2') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
    else elig_factor[2] = '0';
  if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '3') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
    else elig_factor[2] = '0';


 if (np_all gt 0) then elig_factor[3] = '1';
   else elig_factor[3] = '0';
 if (np_black gt 0) then elig_factor[4] = '1';
   else elig_factor[4] = '0';
 if (np_age65 gt 0) then elig_factor[5] = '1';
   else elig_factor[5] = '0';
 if (np_hisp gt 0) then elig_factor[6] = '1';
   else elig_factor[6] = '0';

 elig_factor[7] = occ;
 elig_factor[8] =vac;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually even easier if you use the boolean results.  The only difference below is that it returns numeric results - if you must have `'1'` then `put` each of these to a character or wrap each of them in `cats`.

```
 if ("&r_start" eq 1) then 
 do;
   elig_factor[1] = ( 2011<=built <= 2014) ;
   elig_factor[2] = (status eq '1' and hudadmin in ('1','2','3'));
   elig_factor[3] = (np_all gt 0) ;
   elig_factor[4] = (np_black gt 0);
   elig_factor[5] = (np_age65 gt 0);
   elig_factor[6] = (np_hisp gt 0);
   elig_factor[7] = occ;
   elig_factor[8] = vac;
 end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost answered the question yourself when you said:

> when status is =1 and hudadmin is in 1 or 2 or 3

I'm not sure why you haven't used the `in` operator here.

Anyway, to explain what your code is *actually* doing:

```
if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '1') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
    else elig_factor[2] = '0';

  if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '2') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
    else elig_factor[2] = '0';

  if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '3') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
    else elig_factor[2] = '0';
```

Each `if` statement is evaluated in turn, ignoring the results of the past `if` statements. So, if you have a situation where `hudadmin = 1` then the first `if` statement is triggered, setting `elig_factor[2]` to `'1'`, the subsequent `else` is ignored.

When the *second* `if` statement is reached, it is checked and found to be `FALSE`, so the `else` statement is run, setting `elig_factor[2]` to `'0'`, despite having previously set it to `'1'`.

So you have two options:

**Amend your code so it does what you want**

```
if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '1') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
else if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '2') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
else if (status eq '1' and hudadmin eq '3') then elig_factor[2] = '1';
else elig_factor[2] = '0';
```

This checks if `hudadmin = '1'`, if not then it checks if `hudadmin='2'`, if not then `'3'`, only once it has checked `hudadmin` is not `'1'`,`'2'` or `'3'` then it will set `elig_factor[2] = '0'`.

The code is sound, but a little over engineered, I would go with the following approach

**Use the `in` operator**

```
if (status eq '1' and hudadmin in ('1','2','3')) then elig_factor[2] = '1';
else elig_factor[2] = '0';
```

This checks the condition in one statement, is easier to read, and is arguably more efficient.

Comment: Thanks youre right, and now it works. Thank you so much.